# Is it possible to stub native methods using MacRuby and rspec?

Tags: rspec, macruby

I am trying to use rspec together with MacRuby to test a framework written in Objective-C.

However it does not seem to be possible to stub certain selectors using this approach. For example:

```
Foo.stub(:currentSession).and_return(double("session"))
```

results in:

```
RuntimeError:
       cannot remove method `obfuscated_by_rspec_mocks__currentSession' because it is a native method
     # /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.11/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/rspec-mocks-2.8.0/lib/rspec/mocks/method_double.rb:108:in `block'
```

Also it doesn't seem possible to stub a selector that takes multiple arguments and provide an implementation, for example trying to stub `setObject:forKey:` on `NSMutableDictionary`, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary.any_instance.stub(:setObject)  do |*args| 
   puts *args
end
```

Does nothing.

I've tried various combinations of MacRuby and rspec versions (MacRuby 0.10, 0.11 and rspec 2.5 and 2.8) and the behaviour seems to be the same. I've also tried specifying variants of the selector name such as ":setObject:forKey" etc with no luck.

Is this a bug or simply a limitation of rspec and macruby? Is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

For the selector of an objective-c method with multiple arguments, use a string, not a symbol, that includes the ':' separators between the named argument portions of the method name and the arguments. E.g.

```
class C
  attr_accessor :my_prop
end

o = C.new
o.send('setValue:forKey:', 'hohoho', :my_prop) # => #<C:0x4013fd2e0 @my_prop="hohoho">
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that (I think I tried this variant already but will double check)

Comment: Unfortunately this fails in the rspec context, because it tries to define a method with that name, so you get:      Failure/Error: NSMutableDictionary.any_instance.stub("setValue:forObject:")  do |*args|
     SyntaxError:
       /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.11/usr/lib/ruby/Gems/1.9.2/gems/rspec-mocks-2.8.0/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance/recorder.rb:171: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '\n'
                   def setValue:forObject:(*args, &blk)

Comment: Just came across a MacRuby spec that shows the syntax for objc-style argument should in fact be a symbol with quotes around it, including all colons. So try: :'setValue:forObject:' as the parameter to stub().